# A function on binary vectors

Tags: combinatorics, vectors, binary-operations

I am looking for a function $f:\{0,1\}^d \to \{0,1\}^{d'}$, where $d'<5d$, such that whenever $x,y,z$ are three distinct $d$-dimensional binary vectors, and for all $i\in\{1,\dots, d\}$ it holds that $x[i]\in\{y[i],z[i]\}$ then there exists $j\in \{1,\dots, d'\}$, such that $f(x)[j]\not\in\{f(y)[j],f(z)[j]\}$.

For example, if $x = 10010101$, $y = 10100101$, $z = 00010000$, then I would like to have something like $f(x) = 1{\color{red}1}00001111$, $f(y) = 1{\color{red}0}11111111$, $f(z) = 1{\color{red}0}00000000$.

Is it possible to construct such a function? I tried playing with XOR (aka bitwise addition modulo 2) in different settings (for example XORing the consecutive dimensions, or some permutations of digits, etc.), but this approach seems to be completely wrong.

Any hint, or other kind of help will be extremely useful.

Comment: $j \in \{1, .., d'\}$ maybe? Can you also provide an example of a function with $d'$ large enough so that it always work?

Comment: Yes, $d'$, thank you, I edited the question. Well, we could do something silly and make $d' = 2^d$ and then linearly order all the elements of $\{0,1\}^d$ as $x_1,\dots, x_{2^d}$ make $f(x_i) = 00...010...0$ where $1$ is in $i$-th place, if that's what you mean :)

Comment: Yes this is what I meant. So I understand it works easily for exponential order of $d$, but what about polynomial or linear? As you ask for simply $5d$ it makes me think that you maybe know how to do it for, say $10^5 d$?

Comment: $5d$ is simply a placeholder for linear. Even if I could do it in $10^5d$, it would be great, then I would try to get the constant down as much as possible.

Comment: Are you missing an if somewhere? Do you mean *for all $i\in\{1,\dots, d\}$*

Comment: **if**  *it holds that $x[i]\in\{y[i],z[i]\}$*  **then** *there exists $j\in \{1,\dots, d'\}$, such that $f(x)[j]\not\in\{f(y)[j],f(z)[j]\}$.*

Comment: I put "whenever" instead of "if", but I believe the question is written reasonably. In essence, if for three distinct $d$-dimensional binary vectors $x,y,z$ it holds that for all $i$ $x[i]\in \{y[i],z[i]\}$ then for some $j\in \{1,\dots, d'\}$ we have that $f(x)[j]\not\in \{f(y)[j], f(z)[j]\}$.

Comment: In order to have three distinct bit vectors $x, y, z$ meeting the condition, $y$ and $z$ must differ in at least two bits, as $x$ must match both on all bits where they agree, and if $y$ and $z$ only differ in one bit, $x$ would have to equal one or the other. If you can find a solution that works for $d = 2$, it almost certainly will be scalable to higher $d$. For $d=2$, the only inputs possible (barring exchange of $y$ and $z$) are $(x,y,z) = (1,0,3), (2,0,3),(0,1,2),(3,1,2)$

Comment: It was easy to find a solution for $d = 2$: $f(x) = x[1]\text{ XOR }x[2]$, but my belief that it would be scalable was clearly wrong. You might look at this from an information theory standpoint. For each $x$, there are $3^d -3$ pairs $(y,z)$ satisfying the condition. Haven't gotten further than that.